# Edit and save a file on server (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page that displays the content of a C++ file into a `textarea` and I need to be able to save the contents of it using a script. (The C++ file does not have to be configured just saved.)

I'm using a PHP script to load the code from a file to display it on the `textarea`. How can I send back the contents to the script and save it to the same file or to a file with a new name?

PHP, HTML file:

```php
<?php
$file = '/var/www/cgi-bin/cpp_get3.cpp';
$content = file_get_contents($file);
?>
<input type="text" id="filename" value="cpp_get3.cpp"><br>
<textarea id="cpp_content" rows="15"> 
<?php
   echo($content);
?>
</textarea><br/>
<button id="save"onclick="savefile();">save</button>
```

Script:

```
function savefiles() {
    var contentArea = document.getElementsById('cpp_content');
    var cpp_content = contentArea.value;
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', '/php/save_contents.php', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

    request.onload = function() {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
            console.log("Success");
            var resp = this.response;
        } else {
        alert ("Target server reached, but it returned an error" );
        }
    };
    request.onerror = function() {
      // There was a connection error of some sort
    };
    request.send(cpp_content);
}
```

PHP file:

```php
<?php
$filename = '/var/www/html/cgi-bin/cpp_get3.cpp'; 
$cpp_content = $_POST['cpp_content'];

if(file_exists($filename)){
        file_put_contents($filename, $cpp_content);
}
?>
```

I expect for the C++ file of a text file at this point to get save with the content in the `textarea`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't deserve me ;)

```
<?php

$fn = 'example.cpp';

file_exists($fn) or touch($fn);

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    var_dump($_POST);
    $_POST['filename'] === $fn or $fn = $_POST['filename'];
    file_exists($fn) or touch($fn);
    file_put_contents($fn, $_POST['cpp_content']);
}

$file = file_get_contents($fn);

?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="hi.php" method="post">
    <h1>ig @WookieeTyler</h1>
    <input type="text" name="filename" value="<?=$fn?>">
    <br>
    <textarea name="cpp_content" rows="15">
    <?= htmlspecialchars($file); ?>
    </textarea>
    <br/>
    <button id="save" type="submit">save</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but also you're gonna get hacked if you use this :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to send the contents to a separated PHP file through an XMLHttpRequest. This way you don't have to reload the page when saving. Something like this:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', '/my/url/save_contents.php', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

request.onload = function() {
  if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
    // Success!
    var resp = this.response;
  } else {
    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
  // There was a connection error of some sort
};

request.send('cpp_content=' + cpp_content);
```

Comment: I see what you mean but it is not saving the new content. In the save_files.php file I assign the path of the file to $filename and use this, $cpp_content = $_POST['cpp_content'] to get the new content, then use " file_put_contents($filename, $cpp_content);". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Right. That's because in my example I didn't send the data as a key=value pair. Try changing the las line with this `request.send('cpp_content=' + cpp_content);`

Comment: I went ahead and did a simple page on my localhost and it worked, so thank you for that. However, it wont work on the actual page I'm working on. I don't understand why but thanks a lot because now I know that it actually works.